# Is there a tool to compile "selective" assemblies containing only certain types?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, dependencies, .net-assembly

Say I have a large project containing the types `A` through `Z`.

What if, for whatever reason, I want to package and distribute *just* type `A` to some client(s)?

Obviously I cannot just compile `A` into its own DLL unconditionally; it may depend on some other types in my project. But it's unlikely it depends on *every* type in my project.

What I'm envisioning is some tool that could examine `A`, identify its dependencies, and somehow compile a minimal DLL with only the types required for the type I want (`A`) and no more.

So for example if `A` depends on functionality provided by `B` and `C`, and `B` depends on `D`, but `C` and `D` have no additional dependencies (aside from possibly `A`, `B`, or each other), this tool would take `A` through `D` and compile *just those types* into a DLL for me to do with as I see fit.

Is such functionality available through Visual Studio? If not, is there some add-in or external tool capable of doing this? Incidentally, is what I'm asking about even reasonable, or do you feel that something like this would be a bad idea?

Obviously I could always do this manually; it just seems like that would be a lot of work (and if it's a bad idea to begin with, well, then just forget it).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an ideal problem for a make file. I don't know how the .NET bit will play into it but for the classic C model you could do something like this:

```
clean :
    del *.obj

libA.lib : A.obj
    makelib *.obj

libB.lib : B.obj
    makelib *.obj

...

A.obj : B.obj C.obj
    compile A.cs

B.obj : C.obj D.obj
    compile B.cs

C.obj : 
    compile C.cs

D.obj : 
    compile D.cs

...
```

Run `make clean A` and you should get everything you need for A and nothing more.